# Allowing special characters which are not safe : Web Application

Tags: java

We recently had App Scan done on our application. As per fix for App Scan, we are not allowing `` \r`\n `` along with many other chars. Why are these chars dangerous? What if I have text box where users can type whatever they want? How to handle this scenarios?

Comment: What kind of application is this? A desktop app? A web site? What technologies are used?

Answer (score 1):

Blocking common characters without knowing why you're blocking them is [cargo-cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).  If you have a tool that tells you "these characters are bad and should never be allowed", find a better tool, or at least try to gain a better understanding of *why* it tells you that.

There are cases where blocking certain characters is appropriate, but what you're doing here is really just a (bad) workaround for problems that may exist somewhere else in your program, such as [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Those problems can be better solved in other ways that don't involve limiting what characters users are allowed to type.

In the case of SQL injection:  use prepared statements with bind parameters to keep the user input out of the actual SQL string, so that "special characters" in the user input have no special meaning and can't change the query.

```
// User's input might contain special characters like quotes
String userInput = "'); drop all tables; select ('";

// SQL statement just has a '?' placeholder where the user input should go
String sql = "insert into comments values (?)";

try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
  statement.setString(1, userInput);  // Value for the first '?' in the query

  statement.executeUpdate();  // Perfectly safe!
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for escape sequence. Check apache API [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html)

Comment: Do you mean  I have to escape all these chars before i submit it to my servlet or action class ? The app scan will still catch this as I issue i Guess.